# QueryString not Deserializing to Parameters (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have this function in my Controller

```
public ActionResult postcomment(string gCaptcha,string txtName, string txtEmail, string txtMessage)
```

And I'm passing a JQuery Ajax Querystring (PlainText) as

```
gCaptcha=A&txtName=B&txtEmail=C&txtMessage=D
```

When I pause on the postcomment code, the values of the parameters are blank.  What do I need to do, anything in the RoutesConfig file?

This is my JQuery function.

```
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '@(Request.RawUrl + "/postcomment")',
    dataType: "text",
    data: data,
    contentType: "text/plain; charset=utf-8",
    success: function() {
      alert('success');
    },
    failure: function(response) {
      alert(response.d);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Use the `[FromUri]` attribute on each of your parameters (e.g. `[FromUri]string gCaptcha,[FromUri]string txtName...`). `POST`s generally expect parameters to come from the body, so you need to override this via the attribute.

Comment: `data: { gCaptcha: 'A', txtName: 'B', txtEmail: 'C', txtMessage: 'D' },` and remove `contentType: "text/plain; charset=utf-8",`

Answer (score 0):

I've also had issues with the values being null on a post. What I would do is create an object and make that object a parameter on the action method. So you would do something like:

```
public class CommentViewModel
{
  public string gCaptcha { get; set; }
  public string txtName { get; set; }
  public string txtEmail { get; set; }
  public string txtMessage { get; set; }
}

public ActionResult postcomment(CommentViewModel comment)
```

And as Stephen mention in his comment make your data a json object and remove contentType from the Ajax call